# javascriptでのファイル作成

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

ドラッグアンドドロップされたローカルファイルを
別のローカルフォルダにコピーするような処理を考えています。

対応ブラウザはIE11のみとします。

ドラッグアンドドロップで取得したfileオブジェクトを元に
別のローカルフォルダにコピーすることは可能なのでしょうか？
`<input type="file">`での取得であれば、パスが取得できるので実装は容易ですが、
現在パスの取得方法がわからず、困っています。
パスを使用しなくとも、何かしらの方法でファイルを目的の階層にコピー又は作成できれば問題ありません。
使用言語はPHP,javascriptになります。PHPを利用した方法でも構いません。

申し訳ありませんが、どうかお願いします。

```
<div id="drag_zone"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('dragover', '#drag_zone', function(evt){
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy';
    });
    $(document).on('drop', '#drag_zone', function(evt){
        // 移動先ファイルパス宣言
        var path = 'C://hoge/';
        // fileオブジェクト読込
        var files = evt.target.files;
        for(var i = 0; i < files.lenght;i++){
            // ここでパスを取得してファイルをコピーするか、
            // バイナリデータか何かしらを使用してフォルダに新しいファイルを
            // 新規作成したい。
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この記事が参考になると思います。
[JavaScriptでファイル操作！？ File APIを使いこなそう](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1112/16/news135.html)

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。  

そちらの記事で紹介されているFileAPIでは、Blobデータで管理して、ブラウザ上で出力は行っているのですが、取得した情報を元にローカルファイルへ新規作成及び、コピーは行ってなかったように記憶しております。

テキストファイルであればFileAPIで何ら問題は無いのですが、今回は画像データや圧縮ファイルが移動の対象となっておりまして、そこがネックになっているのかなと思っています。

画像データや圧縮ファイルも該当に含まれることを後出しで出すような形になってしまい申し訳ありません。  
  
紹介してくださった記事で、私の想定していることが可能なのであればいいのですが、当方の理解力が浅く気づいていないだけかもしれないので、もしできるのであれば方法をご提示していただければ幸いです。

Comment: 参考サイトの2ページ目(http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1112/16/news135_2.html)
が保存について記載されています。サンプルはテキストですが、Blob形式(Binary Large Object)なので、バイナリデータとして扱っていると解釈できます。つまり、画像でも、圧縮形式でもバイナリデータとして読み込んで、バイナリデータとして書き出すことができるのだと思います。

後、別のサイトですが「FileSystem　APIについて知る」(http://www.html5rocks.com/ja/tutorials/file/filesystem/)というサイトではコピーの方法も記載されていました。こちらも参考にしてみてください。

Comment: すみません。返信が遅れてしまいました。
上司と相談した結果、他作業との工数のこともあり、別の妥協案で実装することとなりました。ご丁寧に回答していただきありがとうございます。次回システム構築を行う際に機会がありましたら、使用させていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

クライアント側のファイルシステムに(ブラウザ上で動作する)Javascriptからアクセスすることは基本的に不可能です。
例外的にFilesystemAPIというものがありますが、これは一部のブラウザでしか利用できません。

もしなんらかのデータをファイルとして保存させたい、というのならばブラウザのダウンロード機能を利用することになります。
IEであればnavigator.msSaveOrOpenBlobなどを利用することになるでしょうか。
むろんこの場合の挙動はブラウザのダウンロード機能の設定次第となり、デフォルトではユーザーの「ダウンロード」ディレクトリに保存されるでしょう。

Comment: user14064さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。やはりjavascriptでファイルにアクセスすること自体基本的に無理なのですね。今回の仕様上NASにデータを保存したかったこともあり、ダウンロード機能は使えないので別の方法を考えて見ます。ありがとうございました。